# How do I change the alignment of a list item in regards to an image?

Tags: html, css

I am creating an ordered list of images using uppercase letters instead of numbers. When I insert the image the line letter (A, B, etc) is aligned to the bottom of the image and I would live to move it to the top of the image. [Here is an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf2eq.png)

```html
<ol type="A">
  <li><img alt="" height="56" src="prod-dp-cms-api.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/EM_2_EQ_409_fb2217130b.png" width="400" /></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Yah I am very very new at coding and am asking for what I'm sure is a basic technique. Here's the code I have but I am unsure of what is needed to move the image or line letter around?  Here's what I have, I understand I have no type of alignment or padding code yet. <ol type="A">
 <li><img alt="" height="56" src="https://prod-dp-cms-api.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/EM_2_EQ_409_fb2217130b.png" width="400" /></li> </ol>

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to recommend something without seeing the html layout. Is the letter just a text or is it inside it's own element (usually better approach)?

I like to use flex, this can do what you want when
applied to parent container element:

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
```

or simply

```
 vertical-align: text-top;
```

There is plenty of other ways, as I said, depends on the layout.

Answer (score 0):

```css
img{
vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<ol type="A">
  <li><img alt="" height="56" src="prod-dp-cms-api.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/EM_2_EQ_409_fb2217130b.png" width="400" /></li>
</ol>
```